# The simplest way to join 2 files using bash and both of their keys appear in the result

Tags: bash, join

I have 2 input files

file1

```
A   0.01
B   0.09
D   0.05
F   0.08
```

file2

```
A   0.03
C   0.01
D   0.04
E   0.09
```

The output I want is

```
A   0.01    0.03
B   0.09    NULL
C   NULL    0.01
D   0.05    0.04
E   NULL    0.09
F   0.08    NULL
```

The best that I can do is

```
join -t'    ' -a 1 -a 2 -1 1 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,2.2 file1 file2
```

which doesn't give me what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write:

```
join -t $'\t' -a 1 -a 2 -1 1 -2 1 -e NULL -o 0,1.2,2.2 file1 file2
```

where I've made these changes:

- In the output format, I changed `1.1` ("first column of file #1") to `0` ("join field"), so that values from file #2 can show up in the first field when necessary. (Specifically, so that `C` and `E` will.)
- I added the `-e` option to specify a value (`NULL`) for missing/empty fields.
- I used `$'\t'`, which Bash converts to a tab, instead of typing an actual tab. I find this easier to use than a tab in the middle of the command. But if you disagree, and the actual tab is working for you, then by all means, you can keep using it. :-)