# using awk how to merge 2 files, say A & B and do a left outer join function and include all columns in both files

Tags: bash, awk

I have multiple files with different number of columns, i need to do a merge on first file and second file and do a left outer join in awk respective to first file and print all columns in both files matching the first column of both files.

I have tried below codes to get close to my output. But i can't print the ",', where no matching number is found in second file. Below is the code. Join needs sorting and takes more time than awk. My file sizes are big, like 30 million records.

```
awk -F ',' '{  
    if (NR==FNR){ r[$1]=$0}
    else{ if($1 in r) 
    r[$1]=r[$1]gensub($1,"",1)}
}END{for(i in r){print r[i]}}' file1 file2
```

> file1

```
number,column1,column2,..columnN
```

> File2

```
numbr,column1,column2,..columnN
```

> Output

```
number,file1.column1,file1.column2,..file1.columnN,file2.column1,file2.column3...,file2.columnN
```

> file1

```
1,a,b,c
2,a,b,c
3,a,b,c
5,a,b,c
```

> file2

```
1,x,y
2,x,y
5,x,y
6,x,y
7,x,y
```

> desired output

```
1,a,b,c,x,y
2,a,b,c,x,y
3,a,b,c,,,
5,a,b,c,x,y
```

Comment: Please, show us the code you have tried and the problems you have found.

Comment: how many rows do you have? I can provide a simple script to parsing but will be terrible slow for big files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The simplest way to join 2 files using bash and both of their keys appear in the result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736252/the-simplest-way-to-join-2-files-using-bash-and-both-of-their-keys-appear-in-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR {
    tail = gensub(/[^,]*,/,"",1)
    if ( FNR == 1 ) {
        empty = gensub(/[^,]/,"","g",tail)
    }
    file2[$1] = tail
    next
}
{ print $0, ($1 in file2 ? file2[$1] : empty) }

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
1,a,b,c,x,y
2,a,b,c,x,y
3,a,b,c,,
5,a,b,c,x,y
```

The above uses GNU awk for gensub(), with other awks it's just one more step to do [g]sub() on the appropriate variable after initially assigning it.

An interesting (to me at least!) alternative you might want to test for a performance difference is:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR {
    tail = gensub(/[^,]*,/,"",1)
    idx[$1] = NR
    file2[NR] = tail
    if ( FNR == 1 ) {
        file2[""] = gensub(/[^,]/,"","g",tail)
    }
    next
}
{ print $0, file2[idx[$1]] }

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
1,a,b,c,x,y
2,a,b,c,x,y
3,a,b,c,,
5,a,b,c,x,y
```

but I don't really expect it to be any faster and it MAY even be slower.

Comment: Hi Ed, if you very well give an explanation to the code it will be helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
   FNR==NR{d[$1]=substr($0,index($0,",")+1); next}
   {print $0, ($1 in d?d[$1]:",")}' file2 file1
```

you get,

```
1,a,b,c,x,y
2,a,b,c,x,y
3,a,b,c,,
5,a,b,c,x,y
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, but i need to use awk, as this needs sorting and takes more time.

Comment: Hi, my problem is i have different column numbers in different files, for eg: below case doesnt work with your code. And if you can explain what you did will be of great help

[cmsuser@cms-app02 churn_awk]$ cat t4
1,ee,rr
2,rr,rr
3,tt,rr
5,mm,mm
[cmsuser@cms-app02 churn_awk]$ cat t1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
[cmsuser@cms-app02 churn_awk]$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==NR{d[$1]=substr($0,index($0,",")+1); next} {print $0, ($1 in d?d[$1]:"NULL")}' t4 t1
1,ee,rr
2,rr,rr
3,tt,rr
4,NULL
5,mm,mm
6,NULL
7,NULL
8,NULL
9,NULL
10,NULL

Comment: desired output,
1,ee,rr
2,rr,rr
3,tt,rr
4,NULL,NULL
5,mm,mm
6,NULL,NULL
7,NULL,NULL
8,NULL,NULL
9,NULL,NULL
10,NULL,NULL

basically i need final output to have same number of columns

Comment: t1 file, have space char as separator  "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10", your input example doesn't look the same

Comment: Hi Sorry, its actually line by line, somehow it does not show when i paste it here. 

i found a fix, but manual effort each time.

that is to add number of comma's based on the columns of output file

for eg: if my output file is 5 column, then i give like this

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==NR{d[$1]=substr($0,index($0,",")+1); next} {print $0, ($1 in d?d[$1]:",,,,")}' file2 file1

Answer (score 0):

`join` to the rescue:

```
$ join -t $',' -a 1 -e '' -o 0,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.2,2.3 file1.txt file2.txt
```

**Explanation:**

`-t $','`: Field separator token.

`-a 1`: Do not discard records from file 1 if not present in file 2.

`-e ''`: Missing records will be treated as an empty field.

`-o`: Output format.

**file1.txt**

```
1,a,b,c
2,a,b,c
3,a,b,c
5,a,b,c
```

**file2.txt**

```
1,x,y
2,x,y
5,x,y
6,x,y
7,x,y
```

**Output**

```
1,a,b,c,x,y
2,a,b,c,x,y
3,a,b,c,,
5,a,b,c,x,y
```

Comment: comma doesn't need quotes or escaping `-t,` will work as well.